# Is accessing CPU cache (read and write) through C# possible?

Tags: c#, cpu, second-level-cache

I want to know if there are implemented stuff in C# which allows to access CPU cache. It is just interesting for me but I do not have something to do with the cpu cache at the moment. So I was wondering if it is a system limited access or it is avilable to users also. I am talking about L1/L2 or whatever they are called!

Would be nice to hear your comments, external linkes and maybe some code snippets! Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible to write real C# code that does *not* access the cpu cache.  All memory reads and writes go through the cache.  This question makes little sense.

Comment: @Hans Well I am aware that want it or not the cache is going to be filled up with some 0 and 1s but the question was if we can have any kind of control over what is going on there in the cache.

Comment: Make this an answerable question by explaining why you think you need to control the cache.

Comment: @Hans Well I was just wondering if such thing is even exist, Then you are right I should have ask the question another way.

Comment: @HansPassant maybe for http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2046670

Comment: @HansPassant Maybe someone adventurous want to build a OS and BIOS that start from CPU cache instead of RAM, genius.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No programming language has direct access to CPU cache. Reading and writing the cache is something done automatically by the hardware; there's no way to write instructions which treat the cache as any kind of separate entity. Reads and writes to the cache happen as side-effect to all instructions that touch memory.

Comment: A good general answer, perhaps, but [ARM9 can in fact dump cache for review in software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006981/read-cpu-cache-contents?rq=1). I assume it maintains copies of the cache such that some proxy registers are read by software, without being affected by the same operations that are affecting the _actual_ cache.

Comment: That does not seem to be true. I have seen OS developments where for  shared files the L2 is explicitly used. THerefore the OS must have a bit of control, and the OS is programmed in a programming language.

Answer (score 4):

C# is a bit too high level for this type of activity.  Unless you are calling some other library that was written in C/ASM =)  Of course, working with the cache in general is a pretty obscure topic, and for the most part it is controlled entirely by hardware.  On the other hand, there are some pretty interesting questions / discussions on SO that you may have already run across.

[C++ cache aware programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922249/c-cache-aware-programming)
[How can I do a CPU cache flush in x86 Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756825/cpu-cache-flush)

At any rate, despite the limitations, you can still predict (somewhat) what the cache is going to do and take advantage of that for special applications.

Comment: Good point AR, but it becomes harder to do this when you have multiple cores and shared L2 caches and so on.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, this isn't something I would try with a ten foot pole.  I can think of more exciting ways to get a headache =D

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string GetComponent(string hwclass, string syntax)
    {
        var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwclass);
        foreach (var o in mos.Get())
        {
            var mj = (ManagementObject)o;
            CpuModel = Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]);
        }
        return CpuModel;
    }

private string L2CacheSize = HardwareManagement.GetComponent("Win32_Processor", "L2CacheSize");
private string L3CacheSize = HardwareManagement.GetComponent("Win32_Processor", "L3CacheSize");
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer.

Comment: Looks interesting, have you ever tested/benchmarked it?