# examine CPU cache

Tags: embedded, firmware

Is there a way to peek into a cache (instruction and/or data) using JTAG on most modern CPUs? Otherwise, is there any other way too examine the cache content, rather than low-level HW assisting tool ?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: This is going to be very CPU-specific.  Can you tell us what your processor/platform is?

Comment: Atmel's AT91SAM7 to begin with, but I would love to learn of any basic ideas/approaches, if any, to look at cache.

Comment: As Dan mentioned this is extremely cpu specific, and the odds are against having the ability to see the cache without messing it up.  Also if it is possible the chip vendor may choose to not publish that information and keep it for their own design verification.  you can look at the arm core (infocenter.arm.com) that is in the at91sam7 part and see if arm has an mbist or other interface.  If ARM does have an interface that doesnt mean that the chip vendor enabled it or wired it up right, etc.  The memories are foundry specific and not something from arm.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006981/read-cpu-cache-contents